# Mysql ORDER BY varchar column stored as number

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql column (staffid) which format is varchar(11). This column is used to store staff id, which are generally 1,2,3............40,60... I can't use int format for that column as for contractual staff it stores id as cont-1, while for regular staff it stores id as integer 1,2,3... While I am trying to fetch array using a ORDER BY clause with that column, rows are not fetching with correct order. My sql query is:

```
SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY CAST('staffid' as UNSIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```

How can I format that varchar column in mysql query so that for regular staff it treats as integer column as order by that column?

Comment: Debug hint: add `CAST('staffid' as UNSIGNED INTEGER)` to the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

the proper syntax is,

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `database` 
ORDER   BY CAST(staffid AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

since you have mentioned that there are some ids with this format `cont-1`. probably you can add `WHERE` clause to filter specific ID,

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `database`
WHERE   staffid NOT LIKE 'cont%' 
ORDER   BY CAST(staffid AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Comment: Actually I put staffid within 'staffid', that's why it was not working, now when I omitted the [''] (only staffid), it is working properly. JW I have a condition also which filter only regular staff which I did not mention in question for simplicity.

Comment: another explanation is because wrapping an identifier with single quotes make it a string literal. `Column` names as well as `Table` names are identifiers. They are not string literals. If somehow these names happens to be a reserved keyword, they can be escaped using backticks not single quotes.